# Joining two foregin keys in the same table references the same primary key

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to join multiple tables(`BooksReview`, `Followers`, `Books`) with `Users` table which the `Books` references `userId` from `Users`, `BooksReview` references `userId` which is the `userId` who reviewed a book and references `bookId` from `Books` which is the book id that been reviewed on and last but not least the `Followers` table(and here I think where the problem is) has two references from the same primary key it has `follower` from `userId` in `Users` table and `followed` also from `userId` in `Users` table.

The Problem: I created a MySQL query to fetch the number of books reviews for specific book based on specific user, and to fetch number of books for this user and the number of followers he/she has, but when I added the `Followers` join part to my query it shows 0 result for all values which the expected values are 4 books, 4 reviews, and 1 follower.

I have tried to change the join types in the query but it endup with the same result and searched joining two foregin keys in the same table for the same primary key but I didn't find anything useful.

````
```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Authors`.`Users` (
`userId` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
`birthday` DATE NULL,
`aboutMe` TEXT(300) NOT NULL,
`facebookAccount` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`twitterAccount` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`linkedinAccount` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`profileImage` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```
````

````
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Authors`.`Books` (
`bookId` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`bookCategory` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`bookCover` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`bookDescription` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 `userId` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`price` DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL,
`introduction` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`bookId`),
 INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `userId`
 FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
 REFERENCES `Authors`.`Users` (`userId`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;    
 ```
 ```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Authors`.`BooksReview` (
`bookId` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`rateMessage` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`rateNumber` DECIMAL(1,1) NULL,
`userId` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `bookId`
 FOREIGN KEY (`bookId`)
 REFERENCES `Authors`.`Books` (`bookId`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `userId`
 FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
 REFERENCES `Authors`.`Users` (`userId`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
 ```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Authors`.`Followers` (
`follower` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`followed` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 INDEX `follower_idx` (`follower` ASC),
 INDEX `followed_idx` (`followed` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `follower`
 FOREIGN KEY (`follower`)
 REFERENCES `Authors`.`Users` (`userId`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `followed`
 FOREIGN KEY (`followed`)
 REFERENCES `Authors`.`Users` (`userId`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
````

```
THIS IS THE QUERY
SELECT count(br.bookId) AS reviewsCount, count(b.bookId) AS booksCount, count(f.follower) AS followersCount
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN Books AS b ON b.userId = u.userId
JOIN Followers AS f ON b.userId = f.followed AND f.follower = u.userId
INNER JOIN BooksReview AS br ON br.bookId = b.bookId 
                    AND b.bookId IN (SELECT bookId 
                                     FROM Books 
                                     WHERE userId = 'dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956');
```

I expect the result should be 1 follower, 4 books and 4 reviews
but the actual result is 0's for all.

DML:

`Users` ->

```
       userId: dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956

       username: mostafabbbaron
```

etc...

`Books` ->

```
       userId: dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956

       bookId: 5f39c1ae-5e99-4b3a-8ee0-97a80c1ba9b1
```

etc...

`Followers` ->

```
       follower: dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956

       folllowed: b39c8e0c-4124-4339-8c30-e1fc8db5f2d4
```

etc...

`BooksReviews` ->

```
       userId: dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956

       bookId: aa44a455-dc28-476f-b4b9-47563a717f03
```

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong either way. But the reason for getting zeros as result are probably these conditions: `b.userId = u.userId` and `b.userId = f.followed AND f.follower = u.userId`.

IF `b.userId = u.userId` and `b.userId = f.followed` then `f.followed = u.userId`

IF `f.followed = u.userId` and `f.follower = u.userId` then `f.followed = f.follower`

That means that the user must follow himself/herself, which I doubt is the case.

I would write the query the following way:

```
SELECT
count(DISTINCT b.bookId) AS booksCount,
count(br.bookId) AS reviewsCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Followers AS f WHERE f.followed = u.userId) AS followersCount
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN Books       AS b  ON b.userId  = u.userId
LEFT JOIN BooksReview AS br ON br.bookId = b.bookId 
WHERE u.userId = 'dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956'
```

Note: While it's fine to have `Users LEFT JOIN Books LEFT JOIN BooksReview`, because you have a "relation chain" `Users <- Books <- BooksReview`. But you shouldn't just JOIN the `Followers` table, because it's not really related to `Books` or `BooksReview`, and doesn't fit into that chain. That is why I used a subquery in the SELECT clause, to count the followers.

Comment: Nice to see, you could fix my answer. But you can use `u.userId` in the subquery instead of hardcoded `'dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956'`. This way you avoid diplication, and only need to change it in one place.

Comment: thank for the useful reply, but the distinct keyword already removes duplication.

Comment: I mean you don't need to write `'dbb21849-ccce-4af1-aa0f-6653919bf956'` twice in the query, as you did in your edit.